# Get the IP of Virtual Box through the host (Mac OS) terminal

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running an Oracle Virtual Box where I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1, hosted in a Mac OS.

Recently I had a GUI error in Ubuntu start up which didn't allow me to access the ubuntu terminal as no graphics were displayed. However, I already knew the IP address so I was able to connect to the VB using ssh from Mac terminal.

The problem is that now I changed network and the IP of VB has also changed and I can't find the new IP in order to ssh and connect to the VB.

I tried scanning the network with `sudo arp-scan -l` but none of the IPs displayed were working with ssh.

The VB is attached to Bridged Adapter and using WiFi.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IP scan of the whole subnet could be done in the following way:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.*
```

So if none of the IP is responding to ssh, then something could be wrong with your guest system.

Comment: I tried this but in my case I have to run the command with 192.168.*.* as the range of IP varies; thus the outcome of this command is very slow and also returns a very big number of IPs which will take ages to check all of them.

Comment: Add testing of ssh connection:
nmap -sS -p 22 192.168.*.*

Comment: Just tried it and returned the following: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname :nmap: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. Also I can't understand why are you choosing to check only the IP range of 192.168.72.*

Comment: Did you try 192.168.*.* ?

Comment: Also you may add filtering: nmap -sS -p 22 192.168.*.* | egrep 'open|closed|filtered', just to see if there any PC with ssh connection enabled

Comment: I tried `sudo nmap -sS -p 22 192.168.*.*` but it also take ages to run.

Comment: Do you have a router that manages your network and could be logged in? If so it can list all live connections.

Comment: If you remember your guest system hostname then use: nmap -sS -p 22 192.168.*.* | grep 'your guest hostname'

Comment: Tried the one with the hostname but returns the following `sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 192.168.3.223, 16) => Network is down
Offending packet: TCP 192.168.20.56:48535 > 192.168.3.223:443 S ttl=52 id=57564 iplen=11264  seq=3726794542 win=1024 <mss 1460>
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 192.168.4.223, 16) => Network is down
Offending packet: TCP 192.168.20.56:48535 > 192.168.4.223:443 S ttl=50 id=48614 iplen=11264  seq=3726794542 win=1024 <mss 1460>`

Comment: Seems you won't be able to reach your guest system this way. Could you just Ctrl+Alt+F1 on your VBox to get to console and reconfigure the network or even fix GUI ?

Comment: I tried to fix GUI in many ways, and it seems that the problem is that I don't have enough space on the disk. However I cannot allocate more space to the VB as I don't have more free space. Nevertheless, this is not the point. It should be a way to find the IP without the UI. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok, how about moving VB to the external HDD drive or even some other PC and then run it again, with more space allocated ? Maybe even to a flash drive ?

Comment: I have already considered those options which are also referred in related threads regarding the GUI error that I am facing. However, it would be very helpful to find a way to get an answer on the original topic of that thread (finding the IP from the host) for future similar issues.

Comment: You may try to find IP by MAC (find it in the running VBox network settings, where you set bridged adapter):
arp -a | grep [mac]

Comment: Again none of the IPs that are returned is the correct one.